# Using javascript on the address-bar to open links

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, href, address-bar

I am trying to open links using javascript on the address-bar of my browser google chrome.

This is the code I'm using:

```
javascript: var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
   window.open(aTags[i].href); 
}
```

For some reason this open only, in a new tab, the last link in `aTags`.

Thanks!

Comment: try -> `window.open(aTags[i].href, "_blank")`

Comment: Are you trying to open in same tab

Comment: @GovindParashar — How could you possibly open multiple links in the same tab?! They are trying to open a new tab for each link,

Comment: @Quentin : It will replace previous open. I am bit confuse about the question thats why I have asked this stupid question. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers, Chrome included, take steps to prevent sites from spamming the user with large numbers of new windows. This prevents you from achieving what you are trying to do.

You need a browser extension to bypass that limitation.

Here are some written by other people:

- [Open Selected Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-selected-links/cbmiafnaglmnkhnohfdkdgaohdhndkjp?hl=en)
- [Open Multiple URLs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-multiple-urls/oifijhaokejakekmnjmphonojcfkpbbh?hl=en)
- [Linkclump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkclump/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj?hl=en)

Comment: Sadly with these extensions I still can't open multiple links using javascript but they are very useful. By the way, you posted "Open Selected Links" two times.

Answer (score -1):

try this -> `window.open(aTags[i].href,"_self");`,  "_self" to open in new tab

`window.open(aTags[i].href,"_blank");`,  "_blank" to open in same tab

Comment: That would replace the *current* document with one of the links, and not open any new windows/tags.

Comment: @Quentin as of your question, you want to open the link in new tab

Comment: .It isn't my question. The OP is trying to open *all* the links in new tabs